# R Shiny: Removing ggplot2 background to make it transparent

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to have my ggplots on R Shiny Server have transparent. My ui.R for plotting is as follows:

```
  plotOutput("malPie", width="95%")
```

in the server.R my plotting function is as follows:

```
 c <- ggplot(dataFrame, aes(x=factor(nrow(dataFrame)),fill=graphX),environment=environment()) + geom_bar(width = 1)
    print(c + coord_polar(theta = "y")+ xlab(xLabel)+ylab(yLabel)+ labs(fill=legendTitle)+ theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank()
   ))
```

and where it's called:

```
  sub <- data
  sub <- subset(sub,sub$mal_tested=="1")
  drawGraph("pie",sub,factor(sub$mal_tested_pos),"Malaria Tests Done",NULL,"Malaria Tested Positive","Malaria")
```

But the graph rendered still has a white background and I want it to be transparent, not white. How do I achieve this? I have attached an image with an arrow showing the plot.
[image: My shiny server application. Note the pie chart has a white background and I want it to be transparent]

How do i change this background? Please help me.

Comment: `?renderPlot` suggests that you can pass a background colour to the png device that shiny appears to be using. The default background colour does depend on the device in R, IIRC pdf and png have different default value.

Comment: just wanted to mention that from what I can see from the screenshot, your shiny app look very nice! Is the code open source? I'm always on the search for complex shiny apps.

Comment: Cross-posting is not so welcome: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/shiny-discuss/fGUYvPYoiPE

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As @baptiste indicated, you also need to pass `bg="transparent"` to the `renderPlot` call:

```
renderPlot({
  ...
}, bg="transparent")
```