# Remove plotOutput() background in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This seems like it should be simple, but I cannot figure it out, and I haven't been able to find anything that works through google.

I just want to remove the entire of the background from a ggplot plot in Shiny, that is, the white part of the image below:

[image]

I have the following code, including...

```
theme(plot.background = element_blank())
```

...but it doesn't seem to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinythemes)

# Define UI logic
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  plotOutput("testplot")
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$testplot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(
          mtcars,
          aes(
            x = disp,
            y = wt
          )
        ) + geom_point() +
        theme(
          plot.background = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank()
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There is no background to your plot, only white.. Do you mean you want transparent background?

Comment: I believe this has an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152312/r-shiny-removing-ggplot2-background-to-make-it-transparent) : set `bg = "transparent"` in the `renderPlot` call.